# category of monoids has all coequalizers as follows.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, equivalence-relations, monoid

The following is from Problem 13 of Chapter 3 in Awodey's Category Theory.

13-Show that the category of monoids has all coequalizers as follows.

1. Given any pair of monoid homomorphisms $f, g: M \rightarrow N$, show that the following equivalence relations on $N$ agree:

(a) $n \sim n^{\prime} \Leftrightarrow$ for all monoids $X$ and homomorphisms $h: N \rightarrow X$, one has $h f=h g$ implies $h n=h n^{\prime}$,

(b) the intersection of all equivalence relations $\sim$ on $N$ satisfying $f m \sim g m$ for all $m \in M$ as well as
$$
n \sim n^{\prime} \text { and } m \sim m^{\prime} \Rightarrow n \cdot m \sim n^{\prime} \cdot m^{\prime}
$$
2. Taking $\sim$ to be the equivalence relation defined in (1), show that the quotient set $N / \sim$ is a monoid under $[n] \cdot[m]=[n \cdot m]$, and the projection $N \rightarrow N / \sim$ is the coequalizer of $f$ and $g$.

> i can solve "1". how we can solve "2" ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: @AlexKruckman The O.P. tried to solve the exercise, managed to solve (1) and got stucked on (2), as clearly indicated.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin My probing refers to 2. There are many small checks to be done in 2: checking the induced operation is well-defined, checking it makes the quotient set into a monoid, checking that the projection is a monoid homomorphisms, checking this homomorphism coequalizer $f$ and $g$, and finally checking that the universal property of the coequalizer is satisfied. If the OP can check any of these things, they should tell us, so we can identify what the actual sticking point is. If the OP can't check any of these things, they aren't trying hard enough.

Comment: Given h such that hf =hg, check first that h factors through the coequaliser on the level of set-functions (here it is enough to check that h maps equivalent elements to the same point, use 1. a). After you have done that check that the induced set map is a map of monoids. If you have trouble with the first part, think about coequaliser and quotients in the category of sets first.